# Flutter / XCode: Application is shut down immediately after Building and lost connection to debugger "Lost connection to the debugger on ".." iOS 17.3

Tags: flutter, xcode, debugging, ios17

After upgrading my iPhone to iOS 17.3 I have the problem that I can't build my app normally on my device again.
The app is made with flutter
It shout down immediately and XCode give me the message "Lost connection to the debugger on IPhone".
The app is running on an android phone normally. The same when i download a version from testflight.
The full error is:

```
Lost connection to the debugger on “iPhone”.
Domain: IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain
Code: 22
Recovery Suggestion: Restore the connection to “iPhone” and run “Runner” again, or if “Runner” is still running, you can attach to it by selecting Debug > Attach to Process > Runner.
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2024-01-25 11:14:48 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = DBGLLDBLauncher;
}
--

Event Metadata: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_isCoreDevice" = 1;
    "device_model" = "iPhone11,8";
    "device_osBuild" = "17.3 (21D50)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "dvt_coredevice_version" = "355.7.7";
    "dvt_mobiledevice_version" = "1643.60.2";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 2;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 62043;
    "operation_errorCode" = 22;
    "operation_errorDomain" = IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = DBGLLDBLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 99;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 8192;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_structuredConsoleMode" = 1;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos17.2";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "17.2";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 14.3 (Build 23D56)
Xcode 15.2 (22503) (Build 15C500b)
Timestamp: 2024-01-25T12:14:48+01:00
```

I already updated my mac version and I reset my phone.
I deleted multiple times the app on my phone and tried to build it on my device again.
I also deleted the derived files unter `Library/Developer/Xcode`.
I reinstalled XCode as well.

Anyone has the same problems?

Comment: I have the same issue. I have noticed that a huge memory consumption (I have a lot of API requests with massive  json responses at the app first launch) leads to this behaviour. So try to revise your memory using in Xcode performance tab

Comment: I already trief that. The app isn't using so much memory.

It's even lose it's connection if I open a new created flutter project. Flutter also takes really long to build, install and start via vscode.

I found this on github: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/136197#issuecomment-1766566185. There they similar problems but none of the soulutions helped so far.

Answer (score 0):

What helped for me was kinda a connected solution of everything:
If your application doesn't shut down because of the memory consuption like levgen mentioned in the comment and not because of a broken cable, you can try this (maybe you don't need any of these steps):

0. Remove the derived Data (On Mac: CMD + shift + k, for other see below last source)
1. `flutter upgrade`
2. Make sure `Debug executable` is set in XCode under `Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme`and the Executable is set to the default Runner.app
3. `flutter channel stable`
4. `flutter pub get`
5. `pod install --repo-update`
6. Build app in XCode and then try it in vscode if used

I can also recommend to test firstly with a new flutter project. I got for example also the error message "Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:1039/ #58588". There it helped to restart the computer.

It still takes a lot time to build and crashes after few minutes after starting but at least it creates it now.

Also maybe you need to delete the derived data all the time.

I also tried to rename `/Library/Developer` to `/Library/Developers` and restart XCode and downlaoded the iOS Simulator again. (Can't find the source for that)

Sources that helped:

- [after run xCode lost connection to iPhone - how fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72404083/after-run-xcode-lost-connection-to-iphone-how-fix-it?rq=2)
- [Flutter 2: Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:1039/ #58588](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66916397/flutter-2-error-connecting-to-the-service-protocol-failed-to-connect-to-http)
- [Xcode 13/iOS15 is taking longer than expected to launch, it shows a LLDB related message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69366799/xcode-13-ios15-is-taking-longer-than-expected-to-launch-it-shows-a-lldb-related)
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/136197
- [How can I delete derived data in Xcode 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016143/how-can-i-delete-derived-data-in-xcode-8)